How to add a number at risk table beneath survival curves from multivariate Cox model with clustering?
My first question here. I would like to add a number at risk table to the survival curves from multivariate Cox proportional hazards models that use clustering.
ggadjustedcurves will produce the survival curves I want, but will not add a number at risk table:
library(haven)
aa <- read_sav("data.sav")

library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(gtsummary)

fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Sex + variable1 + variable2 + variable3 + cluster(institution), data = aa)
ggadjustedcurves(fit, data=as.data.frame(aa), variable="Sex", xlab = "Days", ylab = "Outcome", xlim = c(0, 365), risk.table = TRUE) 

The above will generate the curves but not a number at risk table.

finalfit will produce the curves and number at risk table, but only for two variables (sometimes I need to generate a multivariate model):
library(finalfit)
data(aa)
explanatory <- c("Sex", "cluster(institution)")
dependent = "Surv(time, status)"
aa %>%
  surv_plot(dependent, explanatory, xlab="Time (days)", pval=TRUE, legend="none") #surv_plot is in the finalfit package.

The above creates the survival curves and number at risk table, but only for two variables.
library(finalfit)
data(aa)
dependent = "Surv(time, status)"
explanatory2 <- c("Sex", "variable1", "variable2", "variable3", "cluster(institution)")
aa %>%
  surv_plot(dependent, explanatory2, xlab="Time (days)", pval=TRUE, legend="none") #surv_plot is in the finalfit package.

The above does not work.
What am I missing? Does anyone have a fix or workaround to create this table? Or, is the answer simply that a number at risk table cannot be produced for this analysis? Thanks.

Please provide all non-base packages used.

I am importing an SPSS dataset using haven. Then survival, survminer, and gtsummary for the ggadjustedcurves option. Then finalfit for the finalfit option.

Where does surv_plot come from? Please add all this information to your edited post, not here. Please read [MRE] and it would help a lot if you could provide a sample of the data using dput().

Thank you for your help, @Edward. I made some edits to my code above. surv_plot is from the finalfit package. I work for a private corporation and the data are proprietary. I would prefer not to share if possible. If necessary, I could try reproducing the problem in an R dataset.

The adjustedCurves package directly supports what you are looking for, although I wouldn't recommend adding a number at risk table to this type of survival curve estimate. The curves are not based on these numbers, which means that they do not necessarily fit together.

A somewhat hacky solution, since adding a risk table from ggadjustedcurves doesn't appear to be possible, is to create a separate risk table using ggsurvtable and then arrange the two plots together using ggarrange from ggpubr:
Since no data was provided, I'll use the bladder dataset to illustrate.
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggpubr)

fit <- coxph(Surv(stop, event) ~ rx + size + number, cluster = id, data=bladder)

gg_adj <- ggadjustedcurves(fit, data=bladder, variable="rx") 

fit2 <- survfit(Surv(stop, event) ~ rx, data=bladder)
risk_table <- ggsurvtable(fit2, data=bladder, xlim=c(0,50), color = "strata")

ggarrange(gg_adj, risk_table$risk.table, nrow=2, heights=c(2,1))



A hacky solution is better than no solution! :) I was able to get your code to run. However, when I modified it to run on my data, the Number at Risk table was created (the axes and labels) but no numbers were populated in the table. Still, you got me further than I have been able to get so far. I'm going to continue to play around with it. Thank you for your help, Edward!

Could you provide some of your data? Maybe there’s some important differences that could help me modify the code so that it works.
